# Are there looser typescript Dom definitons or settings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-lib-dom

I would like *less correct* types for the `Document` interface. Basically everything is of type `Element` when its always `HTMLElement` that I want. Littering lines like `(document.activeElement.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement).click();` with `as` assertions/casts is not making my code any cleaner and creates ***a lot*** of friction transitioning from js to ts. Would be great if everything in the Document interface dealt with `HTMLElement` or something like `Element & Partial<HTMLElement>`.

I tried seeing if Declaration Merging would let some variation like `interface Document { getElementsByClassName (classNames: string): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;}` to work but it didn't seem like this is the right track.

It looks like typescript 4.5 lets you specify specific lib-dom versions. Is it reasonable or possible to create a user modified lib-dom and target that? [(Announcement)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#supporting-lib-from-node_modules) [(Docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)

---

Currently using but have no requirements on tsc 4.6.4 and

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",}
```